# combine sed d and sed a scripts to a single script

Tags: sed

file xz.txt

```
123
456
789
```

I want to merge

```
sed -i '1d'  xz.txt
sed -i '1a abc' xz.txt
```

I tried

```
sed -i -e '1d' -e '1a abc' xz.txt
```

expect to get

```
456
abc
789
```

but I got

```
456
789
```

sed (GNU sed) 4.7
but it doesn't work, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sed goes line by line, first command `1d` - deleted 1st line, 1st line is gone, there is no more 1st line, that is why second command `1a abc` didn't work. Here is how it should be:

```
$ sed '1d; 2a abc' f
456
abc
789
```

Answer (score 1):

What is going on is that the delete statement automatically ends the processing sequence:

> - **`[1addr]a\`**
>
>       **`text`** Write text to standard output as described previously (yes there is a new-line here)
> - **`[2addr]d`**: Delete the pattern space **and** start the next cycle
>   <sub>**Source: [Posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html))**</sub>

As the `a` command does not modify the pattern space but just writes to `stdout`, you can simply do

```
[POSIX]$ sed -e '1a\
abc' -e '1d'
[GNU]$ sed -e '1a abc' -e '1d'
```

However, the easiest is just to use the replace command `c`:

```
[POSIX]$ sed -e '1c\
abc'
[GNU]$ sed -e '1c abc`
```

Note: The reason the commands `a` and `c` write directly to the output and not to the pattern space is most likely that it would mess up the address ranging using line-numbers.